# What is "trustAnchors"

Tags: java, post, ssl

I have been trying to send a file to a remote server using RESTful service. All I ever get is `Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`. Have used all the suggestions I can find in the Internet and, perhaps, got a little confused what trustAnchors could really be. It's time for the basics, so that I can be more sure of which methods I can use when searching online.

So the questions here are:

1. What is trustAnchors?
2. How can I troubleshoot/debug to narrow down the cause of the issue? I am using Jdk1.7 with eclipse Kepler. Have enabled the arguments 
   `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` in my eclipse.
3. I am sending a file using HTTP POST. Have tried different methods to set using Entity, FileEntity, MultipartEntity, InputStreamEntity, etc. Does it has anything to do with the way I send the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error you get is because the JVM can't find the truststore. Check the path to your trustStore.

What a trustAnchor is, is described on [technopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25264/trust-anchor):

> A trust anchor is a public key and its associated accompanying
>   information. Public keys act as an authority to verify a digital
>   signature’s authenticity. The data associated with a public key
>   delineates what types of information the trust anchor can rule over or
>   what actions it can allow or disallow.